# Как вывести сообщение на сайте для браузера Mozilla

Tags: php

Есть такой код, но он для Chrome а как сделать что для Mozilla выводилось сообщение?

```
<?php
if (!preg_match('/Chrome/i', $ua)) { echo '
Бла бла 
'; }
?>
```

Comment: Нет такого браузера.

Comment: `$browser = get_browser(null, true); if($browser['browser'] == 'Firefox') ...`

Comment: Ну нет значит нет но смысл понятен вить ? Или принципиально у Вас нет ))))

Comment: Kostiantyn Okhotnyk А полный код и где слова вставлять как выглядеть будет ?

Comment: Qwertiy Я прошу простить меня, но как и любой профессионал в своем деле, будет говорить что мол ну как так не знать такое. Я все понимаю и прошу прощения если полез в ваш огород не подготовленным )))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используем функцию [get_browser(user_agent, return_array)](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.get-browser.php)

`user_agent` - это строка какого-нибудь конкретного юзер агента, либо null, что означает что user_agent нужно взять из HTTP заголовка.
`return_array` - булевый параметр отвечающий за формат, который должна отдать функция.

```
<?php


$browser = get_browser(null, true); 
if($browser['browser'] === 'Firefox') {
  echo 'Бла бла'; 
} else if($browser['browser'] === 'Chrome') {
   echo 'Бла бла'; 
}
```

## ОБНОВЛЕНО.

Использовать `HTTP_USER_AGENT`;

```
$uAgent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

if(preg_match('/Firefox/i',$uAgent)) {
   echo 'бла бла';
} else if(preg_match('/Chrome/i',$uAgent) {
   echo 'Бла бла'; 
}
```

Comment: Константин я это понял а бла бла где писать текст свой для вывода ? Дальше  так что ли       '<?php
$browser = get_browser(null, true); 
if($browser['browser'] === 'Firefox') { echo '
Бла бла 
'; }
?>'

Comment: да, правильно )

Comment: Константин такое сообщение пишет: Warning: get_browser(): browscap ini directive not set in /home/h814499477/мойсайт.ru/docs/home/down.php on line 15

Comment: Константин может быть это связанно с версией PHP ?

Comment: в php.ini нужно раскоментировать строку `browscap = "PATH/TO/php_browscap.ini"`. Раскоментировать - это удалить `;` перед `browscap`

Comment: @Helpsetup обновил ответ

Comment: Нашел доступ к PHP.INI но там нет такой строки ?

Comment: Если Я поставлю точку и добавлю .browscap ?

Comment: через HTTP_USER_AGENT у вас не получилось? если строки нет, то скорее [не установлен](https://medium.com/code-kings/browser-cap-how-to-install-upgrade-your-browser-cap-ini-file-155a4cad2206)

Comment: проверьте есть ли по пути  /etc/php5/mods-available/php_browscap.ini этот файл. Конечно если есть доступ. Если нет пробуйте просто через  `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`

Comment: Не понял последнее как через : $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] ?

Comment: @Helpsetup я же обновлял вчера ответ. После слова **ОБНОВЛЕНО** - решение :) В `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` содержится строка юзерагента из которой можно вычислить браузер. как это сделать описано в ответе

Comment: @Helpsetup просто вставьте код в котором фигурирует $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']  )

Comment: Kostiantyn Okhotnyk Спасибо Вам огромное ! Все заработало как надо ))))